# Ajax Get is logged in console but won't print to page

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

Can someone point out the obvious as to why this response isn't printing to the page?

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'https://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2017/scores/gamedetail/0011700003_gamedetail.json', 
  function (data) {
    console.log("THE RESPONSE ", data);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#viewer").html(data);
    }, 4000);


});
```

HTML

```
<div id="viewer"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nolaandy/df0jsdL0/1/

JSFiddle here shows that a JSON object is logged in the console.
I want to access the data in the response. I thought I'd start with just printing out the whole response to the "viewer" div but nothing appears there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is rendered is because `$.html()` accepts a string to render as HTML, and you are providing an object.

If you want your object to be printed as a string, you can refactor to:

```
$("#viewer").html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I think this will be really noisy, especially if the object is large. For debugging purposes, I think you are better off using the console.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0x3j7fk1/

Comment: No problem, @4ndy. Could you mark the question as answered, for others who have this problem in the future? Thanks!